# App Script Functions in Google Sheet Stuck At "Loading..."

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I've been experiencing a couple issues with Google Sheets & App Scripts lately, and I'm hoping someone can help me out. I'm going to contain this post to one topic / question, but I'm going to mention a couple of other problems that I'm having just for a greater context in case the other issues are related or may be causing the problem specific to this topic.

Problem: My custom app script functions in my Google Speadsheet are currently stuck at "Loading..." and at the time of writing this have been for over an hour. There are no logs of it being executed in MyExecution in my App Script Dashboard, nor are there any errors reported anywhere. These functions were working and have been working for the last couple months until today.

Details:
So, in my Google Sheet I'm using a custom method "findSeenCount". It's used quite a few times throughout a couple sheets, and though I don't think the logic is relevant here, I will say that its purpose was to perform a count on specific things too complex to chain the basic spreadsheet counts and conditions together. The function itself works fine, and has for several months now. However, today as I was working on a separate script (working title: newFunction), I started to notice every time I would save my script project or in the editor run -> newFunction, it would trigger all my findSeenCount functions in the sheet to run (as in it would get an entry in the Execution log), but on the sheet itself (where the calls actually were), it never actually went to recalculate. The return values stayed the same, it never changed to "Loading...", but there were executions clearly happening according to the dashboard. This was quite taxing, and strange as at the time I noticed this happening newFunction was just doing 2 simple requests to get some specific sheets, one of which was a sheet with some findSeenCount functions on it (though I've never had this issue before in some of my other functions).

```
function newFunction()
{
var attendanceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Attendance"); 

// Sheet that contains findSeenCount.
var P1Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("P1 Prio");

return;
}
```

At this point, my App Script dashboard -> My Executions page started to become pretty laggy, and eventually just started crashing. No errors were being reported and when the page would load I could see it completing the unwanted executions. It ran a couple hundred times as I was trying to work, which eventually I just removed all the findSeenCount function calls in the sheet entirely. After I did that, any function I tried to trigger would not work. In the sheet, if I called a function it would get stuck on "Loading..." and no execution records would show up on my dashboard -> My Executions. If I ran a function in the editor, it would run, the "running function" box would pop up, eventually go away, and that was it. Again, no execution record would be recorded in the dashboard -> My Executions and it would never actually return any results to the log "Waiting for logs, please wait..." if wrote in a log statement. I'm not seeing any errors anywhere, and I don't think I surpassed any sort of execution limit as I would expect to be told somewhere that I had. On top of this, I've also noticed that I have tons of executions that are recorded, I mean my application sees somewhat heavy traffic daily and has for the last several months. This alone seems to cause a little delay when simply just loading a page of the executions and I'm not sure if there's a way I can clear this list -- but that's getting off topic.

If anyone has any ideas on what's going on, or what I'm supposed to do about this, or where I can find any sort of logging that may be able to give me better details about what the problem is please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: If you want a quick fix  , try clearing your browser cache and cookies and clear your sheet and try adding your formulas again.

Comment: Well there we go. Sometimes the most simple answers are the solution. That did end up fixing the issue. At least in the sheet. ty!

Comment: Worth noting, there is also currently an outage https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097 (not relevant for OP, but relevant for people arriving through Google)

Comment: The problem is that when a custom function formula cell starts showing `Loading...`, the custom function does not get called _at all_. Clearing the cache and cookies does not make a difference. When you clear the sheet and re-insert the formula, it gets re-evaluated, and may well work then. But that does not mean that the problem would have been solved. The new formula will eventually start showing `Loading...` as well, indefinitely. Click **+1** in [issue 222342097](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097) in the issue tracker to vote for fixing this decade-old bug.

Answer (score 2):

I found that editing just one cell with a single formula (say adding a space between the = and the formula and returning) seemed to trigger the whole sheet to refresh and work with all script functions. Not sure if you need to edit a cell with a custom function or whether editing any cell will do this. I think custom functions are an essential tool adding clarity so Google should sort this out. I think Google has got too fat and cosy.

Comment: This worked for me. I just added =1*1 into a random cell and it triggered everything to load

Comment: Forcing the custom function formula to recalculate indeed often causes the custom function to actually get called, resolving the issue _temporarily_. The `=1*1` formula has no magic to it. It will only cause recalculation if the custom function refers to a range that includes the new formula cell.
Click **+1** in [issue 222342097](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097) in the issue tracker to vote for fixing this decade-old bug.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to clear browser cache and cookies and clear the sheet and adding your formulas again.

A more reliable way is to ditch the custom formulas and use triggers or menus or buttons. Custom functions are unreliable at large scale.

Comment: I do not think that clearing the cache and cookies would make any difference, because they pertain to the _client_, while Google Apps Script runs at the _server_. It is the client-server link failing that causes the issue. Clearing and re-inserting helps _temporarily_ because it forces custom function re-evaluation, but the new formula will eventually start showing `Loading...` as well. Click **+1** in [issue 222342097](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097) in the issue tracker to vote for fixing this decade-old bug.

Comment: @doubleunary Client side JavaScript would be calling server side JavaScript. So, why do you think clearing the cache and cookies would not make any difference? Any calls to server would send cookies and I'm sure they make use  of the cache. PS: The issue you mentioned is marked fixed.

Comment: Clearing the formula cell and pressing undo causes recalculation and temporarily "fixes" the issue, regardless of whether you destroy the browser cache and cookies. I hesitate giving advice to clear cookies because that causes a lot of inconvenience to users who use one browser for everything.

Comment: For clarity, there is no user-written client-side JavaScript at play here. Custom functions reside and run at the server only. Their results are [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and returned to the client, which in case of an interactive Google Sheet is Google's code running in the web browser. Google Sheets can also run "headless" entirely at the server, suffering from the same problem, but that is not what is discussed here. The issue has indeed been marked fixed, but the bug remains. It's been causing trouble for a decade.